# formatting struct/class macro definition

Tags: clang-format

We are currently using the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-cppunittestframework-api-reference?view=vs-2019#create_test_classes_and_methods) which defines test classes with a macro, ex:

```
TEST_CLASS(Class1)
{    
public:    
    TEST_METHOD(Method1)
    {
        Logger::WriteMessage("In Method1");
        Assert::AreEqual(0, 0);
    }   
};
```

I am having a hard time getting clang-format to "understand" that TEST_CLASS is a struct/class definition. After trying a couple of things the current best solution I got is to define two new macros to wrap the class:

```
#define START_TEST(className) TEST_CLASS(className){
#define END_TEST };
```

and define them as a block start/end:

```
MacroBlockBegin: ^START_TEST.*$
MacroBlockEnd: ^END_TEST.*$
```

I am wondering if there is a better solution that does not involve adding more macros...

Comment: Try `ForEachMacros: [TEST_CLASS, TEST_METHOD]`, but be aware of the extra space introduced if `SpaceBeforeParensOptions:AfterForeachMacros:true`.